# Namespace and Class names conflict

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, name-collision

I have a class called `Functions` which is in the namespace, let's say `SomeNameSpace`. In the `Functions` class I have a function called `GetCurrentValue` which I am using to create an excel formula to display in the formula bar. I want the formula equation to start with `=SomeNameSpace.Functions.GetCurrentValue` but when I try this

```
using System.IO;
using System;

namespace SomeNameSpace{
  public class Functions{
     public object GetCurrentValue (arg1, arg2...){
     //GetCurrentValue method implementation
     }
  }
}

using System.IO;
using System;
using SomeNameSpace;

namespace AnotherNamespace{
public static bool SetFormula (string newFormula){ //newFormula value is "GetCurrentValue"        
    string sTemp = "=SomeNameSpace.Functions.";
    string Formula = sTemp + newFormula;
    return true;        
}
```

`Formula` only gets set to `=GetCurrentValue`. I also realized that when I change `sTemp` to a string other than `=SomeNameSpace.Functions.`, for example, `=SomeSpace.Functions.`, it works perfect, as in `Formula` gets set to `=SomeSpace.Functions.GetCurrentValue`.

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and, if possible, how I can get to do what I want?

Comment: You're never assigning `Formula` to anything. Do you need to?

Comment: Why do you have the `name-collision` tag? I don't see any naming conflicts.

Comment: you haven't declared `Formula` variable. Also, why is your `SetFormula` of boolean type and why is your `GetCurrentValue` object?

Comment: @KendallFrey can you not clearly see a name collision related problem?  wow

Comment: @mehow All I see is `SomeNameSpace.Functions` and `AnotherNamespace.???`. There is no collision there.

Comment: @mehow I forgot to put the line there but right before assigning the value to Formula is had it set to null.

Comment: Maybe it's because Excel has that name built-in and tweaks the formula (by the way, how are you outputting the formula to the formula bar?)... Which particular name are you using to trigger the conflict?

Comment: @C.B. I doubt excel has this name. About how I am outputting the formula to the formula bar, I didn't write the whole implementation of the SetFormula method because it is too long, but inside of it I have an Excel Range "rg" for which, after getting its row and column information, I update its Formula property using the value of my Formula string. And since I have my application DisplayFormulaBar property set to true, the formula bar gets populated by the value in rg.Formula

Comment: I finally figured it out! I tried and summarized it here http://www.josephnellysugusugira.com/excel-udf-names-conflict/

Comment: @JosephSuguSuguSugira Sadly the link you posted seems to no longer work. It'd be best to post it as an answer on your own (this) question.